# Transformer in a 2-3A charger

Tags: current, transformer, charger, charge

I have opened one of my phone charger to check the transformer used to provide an output of 2-3 A. I am a bit surprised regarding the size of the transformer. It is very small and the wires in the coil seem to be very thin. How could such small and thin wires provide such a large current?

[image]

The circuit of the charger with the transformer in yellow is shown.
[image]

The primary side is shown above:
[image]

The secondary side is shown above

Comment: Considering the single layer Pertinax board, are you sure it really does provide 3 A without overheating?

Comment: Yes it is a fast charger so it can provide a high current...But even if it is 2A it is high for such a small transformer

Comment: Unwind it and measure the secondary wire diameter.

Comment: First, it's likely undersized. Second, ferrite transformers are smaller than we would expect them to be, especially if they run at higher frequencies - a transformer running at 500kHz would need smaller core and shorter wire (fewer turns) than one running at 50kHz. So, its actual physical dimensions are not an exact indicator of the power they can transfer - core material and operating frequency determine its size requirements.

Comment: @EdinFifić I understand that increasing frequency decreases the size of of the transformer but the current. Still a 2A has to be passed. The wires aren't that strong to handle the 2A in my view.

Comment: You didn't give us any measurements, and we can't go just based on your observation without numbers. Additionally, because there are only a few turns/shorter wire, a thinner wire will provide same resistance as a longer thicker wire used at lower frequencies. Again, without actual measurement of the wires, we can't tell. Also, you may be looking at the high voltage side wire.

Comment: please post a picture of the other side of the PCB

Comment: It should be fairly easy to trace the tracks and components. Then you might be able to read resistance of the primary and secondary windings. If the secondary is 0.1 ohms, the power dissipation at 3 A will be just about 900 mW, which is reasonable for a 15 W fast 5V line powered charger. If the input is 120 VAC, the current will be something like 130 mA. If the primary reads 5 ohms, the power losses will be about 85 mW.

Comment: Someone has voted your question down because of the lack of details. Everything we have mentioned and discussed was due to the lack of detail, so you should include at least the information we talked about, as well as the side view of your transformer that shows the wire(s). You're telling about thickness of the wire, but you haven't even shown us a picture of the wire, and didn't provide any measurements of its diameter or resistance.

Comment: As the frequency goes up so does the efficiency to a limit. They run some in the Mhz reagan to keep them small. At 50/60 Hz they are a lot larger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The secondary side looks like it might be two strands of reasonably sized magnet wire for 2-3 A. Why did you take it apart? Was it overheating or malfunctioning? It probably only needs to deliver 2-3 A for 15-20 minutes or so, followed by a much lower current to "top off" the charge.The primary only needs to handle about 125 mA at 120 VAC. Actually, it will likely be as little as 1/3 of that because the FWB rectifier provides 180 to 360 VDC which is then switched at high frequency.

As has been answered in the comments, high frequency switching supplies can be very small compared to 50/60 Hz transformers.

If you are curious about the amount of power dissipated by the windings, you can measure the resistance without unwinding, and calculating the wattage. There will also probably a similar amount of power in core losses.